# listening problem in short dialogue (British accent)

Tags: listening

[**linked dialogue audio file**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U1d-EjPEzUGS_PBE55OOhjZ0gsJzgzvC/view?usp=drive_link)

I'm having difficulties to listen this dialogue.

in the linked dialogue audio file,
the script is...
boy : You think that **would**(4) be a nice snack?
girl : I would eat the whole packet **in**(1) one minute.

but for me, it sounds like ...
boy : you **would**(2) think that be a nice snack?
girl : I would eat **like**(3) the whole packet one minute.

My Question is ....

[Q1] "**in**"(1) is said clearly? it's very hard to listen "**in**".

[Q2] what is the boy's wording if u write down just as u hear it?
(1) boy : You think that **would** be a nice snack?
(2) boy : You **would** think that be a nice snack?

[Q3] what is the gir's wording if u write down just as u hear it?
(1) girl : I would eat the whole packet **in** one minute.
(2) girl : I would eat **like** the whole packet one minute.

thx for reading this.

Comment: It's extremely difficult to understand what either of them is saying, particularly the girl. I think the what the boy says is as the "official" transcription, but I can, like you, hear what may be **like** in the girl's reply, and I agree she says **in**. The best I can do for the girl is "I would(?) eat like the whole packet in one minute". It may well be the "official" transcription has been slightly "tidied up" by the transcriber to make better English in their opinion.

Comment: The speech is very unclear - I think they are both disabled people.

Comment: The audio sounds slowed down but the boy's voice says "that ..uld be" with an incomplete inarticulation of the initial "w" sound of "would".

Comment: The girl says "I would eat like the whole packet i' one mi't" with no nasal sound ending the word "in" and no clear nasal mid-word in "minute"

Comment: @dotoryjub As I said, for the boy, I hear the "official" transcription "You think that would be a nice snack?"

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, quite possibly. I would like to know the source and/or context of this and the OP's other audio files about which they have posted similar questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question. I don't think this is suitable for English Learning. The audio is too distorted.  The speech seems to be disordered, and there is no context for the listening.  The task (transcription) isn't a task for English learners.  The audio is so bad that it is really no better than guesswork as to what they are saying.

Comment: I listened to this several times.  To be honest I can't tell if it is English or not. Utterly unsuitable for English Learning.

Comment: [there are a few people to visit my posts to downvote persistently.] not really understandable and now we have two of these meaningless posts.

Comment: Why **on earth** have you edited your question to remove the question? That is disruptive behavour.

Comment: @ColinFine There are now four posts like this. All the same person who just doesn't understand how the site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the words spoken are:

> (And) you think that would be a nice snack?

> I would eat like the whole pack in one minute.

The first "And" is pretty much swallowed and is spoken as "n" (which is very common). The second speaker may have meant to say "packet" but swallowed the last syllable, but "pack" makes as much sense as "packet". It's possible that the first speaker tries to say "could" instead of "would", but most people say hard Cs even if they are slurring. "Would" makes as much sense as "could".